# How can I pass information by spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and I have a REST API.

I need some informations, for example, Date, Person ... but I have another information where I'll put to add information where will be text.

For example:

```
/addtimesheetjson/{idusuario}/{data}/{latitude}/{longitude}/{other}
```

{other} can be (for example): lorem/ipsum/dolar/ -- the user can put any text there.

When the user sends the information, my system will give error because there are a lot "/".

My question is, how can I pass text where my Spring MVC understand that "/" is information instead of a path of my REST?

Comment: You could try to escape `/` before calling `Rest` URL. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Spring will not handle your case very well and escaping doesn't solve it unfortunately. You will need to find another way to pass the value of `other`. You can add a header to the request e.g. `X-OTHER: /lorem/ipsum/dolar`